# How to get sub sub sub childs with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html construct

```
...

<div cust-attrib-id="root">
  <div cust-attrib-id="root-title"></div>
  <div cust-attrib-id="country">
        <div cust-attrib-id="country-title"></div>
        <div cust-attrib-id="region">
            <div cust-attrib-id="region-title">
                <a href="xx">Frankfurt</a>
            </div>
            <div cust-attrib-id="region-title">
                <a href="xx">Braunschweig</a>
            </div>
            <div cust-attrib-id="region-title">
                <a href="xx">Hamm</a>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
...
```

What is the easiest way to get the `<a>`-Tags with the list of regions in Python when using Beautifulsoap? Each `<a>` tag belongs to a `Div` with the custom attribute `cust-attrib-id` and the value `region-title`.

I am at the div with the custom attriubute-value `root` and i would like to iterate over al sub sub sub `<a>`'s within the `div`'s with the custom attribute `cust-attrib-id` and `value` = 'region-title'.

I am selectingthe root element via

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

rootCategories = soup.select('div[cust-attrib-id="root"]')
```

Now i could find `country`, then find all `region`'s and iterate over the result via `for ... in ...`. But i am looking for a "shortcut" to get these items queried.

So the desired result would be an output like

Frankfurt
Braunschweig
Hamm

and

```
cities = soup.select('div[cust-attrib-id="root"]\\div[cust-attrib-id="country"]\\div[cust-attrib-id="region-title"]')
```

I think having it cascaded in the query makes it more safe, cause attribute value region-title is not unique on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT (based on your changes)

> I think having it cascaded in the query makes it more safe, cause
> attribute value region-title is not unique on the page.

Making your selection as specific as possible is a very good train of thought - Just chain the selectors of attributes and tags to get all the `<a>` you need:

```
soup.select('div[cust-attrib-id="root"] [cust-attrib-id="region-title"] a')
```

To get a list of all the city names you can use your selection and a `list comprehension`:

```
cities = [t.text for t in soup.select('div[cust-attrib-id="root"] [cust-attrib-id="region-title"] a')]
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
html = '''<div cust-attrib-id="root">
  <div cust-attrib-id="root-title"></div>
  <div cust-attrib-id="country">
        <div cust-attrib-id="country-title"></div>
        <div cust-attrib-id="region">
            <div cust-attrib-id="region-title">
                <a href="xx">Frankfurt</a>
            </div>
            <div cust-attrib-id="region-title">
                <a href="xx">Braunschweig</a>
            </div>
            <div cust-attrib-id="region-title">
                <a href="xx">Hamm</a>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

cities = [t.text for t in soup.select('div[cust-attrib-id="root"] [cust-attrib-id="region-title"] a')]
```

#### Output

```
['Frankfurt', 'Braunschweig', 'Hamm']
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have edited my question and added code, output and "expected" solution where i am currently stuck.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, last version looks perfect and should be template for new ones.

Answer (score 1):

On your example "region-title" it what you want, so just get every "region-title"

```
for x in soup.find_all(attrs={"cust-attrib-id": 'region-title'}):
    print(x.getText())
```

Output:

```
Frankfurt
Braunschweig
Hamm
```